# Python subprocess arbitrarily split output between files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I have a multi-step process.  Basically, I need to call subprocess.call (or the equivalent) in a way that it writes stdout to one file (for passing to a next step) and writes both stdout and stderr, properly chronologically interleaved, into another file (for displaying to a user).

I should be able to write a function with a signature like this:

```
def CallProcess(command, outonlyfile, interleavedfile)
```

Where the latter two arguments are files (or preferably file-like objects, though I can work with temp files), such that I can call it as so:

```
import tempfile

foo = tempfile.TemporaryFile('wb+')
bar = tempfile.TemporaryFile('wb+')

CallProcess('echo out1; echo err1 >&2; echo out2; echo err2 >&2', foo, bar)
foo.seek(0)
bar.seek(0)

print('foo:')
print(foo.read())
print()
print('bar:')
print(bar.read())
```

And it should output:

```
foo:
out1
out2

bar:
out1
err1
out2
err2
```

It must be platform-agnostic (So I can't make a call to `tee` or the like).  It should preferably be pure python.

I've tried constructing a Tee object that will output to multiple file handles passed to it, but unfortunately, subprocess.call won't accept a file-like object, only a real file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is not a problem you can solve generally for any subprocess that writes to `stderr` and `stdout` for any operating system. The fundamental problem is that `stdout` and `stderr` are independent at the system level.

Say you have the following code:

Child:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('stdout line 1')
sys.stderr.write('stderr line 2')
```

Parent:

```
# parent process is using select to wait for data on the pipes it set
# up to communicate with the child
readable_fds = select([child.stdout, child.stderr])
```

You cannot be guaranteed that `child.stdout` will have data available before `child.stderr`, even though it was written to `child.stdout` first.

It is easily demonstrable using the following script that quite often the data appears on them both at the same time, in which case how do you know which was written first, and it's not impossible that it could appear on stderr first.

```
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

while True:
    child = Popen('echo hello; echo goodbye>&2', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    rfs, _, _ = select([child.stdout, child.stderr], [], [])
    child.wait()
    if len(rfs) > 1:
        print('Data available on both pipes simultaneously! Cannot interleave correctly.')
        break
```

That's why most logs you'll see have got timestamps in each log message, that way you can put `stdout` and `stderr` in separate files and either compare them in an editor afterwards, or do some post-processing to recombine them.

Alternatively you can put a library into the child process, which can intercept the write to `stdout` / `stderr` calls and correctly interleave them.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid it would have to be something like that.  I was hoping for a clean solution.  Thanks.